# Counting functions $f: A \rightarrow B$ where $|A| \gt |B|$ and $|f(A)| = x$

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I've come across an exercise like this in my discrete maths textbook (Grimaldi), and I'm thoroughly stumped.

Suppose $A = \left\{1, 2,...,n\right\}$ and $B = \left\{1, 2,...,m\right\}$ where $n \gt m$.

How do you count the number of functions $f: A \rightarrow B$ satisfying $|f(A)| = x$ for some fixed non-negative integer $x \lt m$.

My confusion stems from $|f(A)| = x$. What exactly is the cardinality of a function applied to a set? For that matter, what would $|f(1)|$ be?

Comment: It's the cardinality of the image of $f$.  The cardinality of $|f(\{1\})|=|\{f(1)\}|=1$.

Comment: Hint: What is the number of surjective functions from $A$ to $C$ where $|C|=x$.  Now, how many subsets of $B$ are there that have cardinality $x$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Would this then mean that $|f(A)| \leq x$ since non-surjective functions would map to less than $x$ elements in $B$?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean in your last comment, there were too many pronouns.  Could you rephrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let's consider the case where $x=m=5$.  Once you understand this case, the rest will (hopefully) follow.

There are $5^m$ functions $f:A\rightarrow B$, but not all of these are surjective, so we have over-counted.

Each non-surjective function is missing at least one element of $B$.  Let $B_1\subseteq B$ such that $|B_1|=4$.  There are $4^n$ functions to $B_1$.  Since there are $5$ elements of $B$ that could be removed, so this accounts for $5\cdot 4^n$ functions.  However, we've over-counted again because functions which are not surjections onto $B_1$ are also counted twice.

Let $B_2$ be a subset of $B$ of cardinality $3$.  We must add these functions back.  Since there are $\begin{pmatrix}5\\2\end{pmatrix}$ such subsets, we must add back $\begin{pmatrix}5\\2\end{pmatrix}3^n$ functions.  This is adding back too many functions again!

For subsets of cardinality $2$, there are $\begin{pmatrix}5\\3\end{pmatrix}2^n$ functions to sets of cardinality $2$.  This is subtracting too many functions.

We are left with the functions to sets of cardinality $1$, but these are just the constant functions, so there's only $5$ of these.

Summarizing, the number of functions is
$$
5^n-\begin{pmatrix}5\\4\end{pmatrix}4^n+\begin{pmatrix}5\\3\end{pmatrix}3^n-\begin{pmatrix}5\\2\end{pmatrix}2^n+\begin{pmatrix}5\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now, generalize, generalize, generalize!